# Curl bash get a header and the body without string manipulation

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I am using curl and bash to get a config from go cd. i need the header labeled ETag but also want the json body. is there a easy way to do this using curl or do i have to manipulate the result in bash?

```
$ curl 'https://ci.example.com/go/api/admin/pipelines/my_pipeline' \
    -u 'username:password' \
    -H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v6+json' \
    -i
```

returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.go.cd.v6+json; charset=utf-8
ETag: "e064ca0fe5d8a39602e19666454b8d77"
{
     "_links": {
     "self": {
             "href": "https://ci.example.com/go/api/admin/pipelines/my_pipeline"
},
"doc": {
  "href": "https://api.gocd.org/#pipeline-config"
},
...
```

i cannot use jq because it complains about the headers, but i want the ETag header and its value too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl` returns a sequence of CR/LF-terminated lines, with the last line (following an empty line) being the actual body. You can write a code block that first uses a `while` loop to parse the headers out of the standard input, terminating when the header block is complete, then uses `jq` to read the rest of the input. For example:

```
# Consume standard input up to, and including, an empty line.
# Sets global variable 'etag'.
parse_headers () {
  local header etag_regex='ETag: (.*)'
  while read -d $'\r\n' header; do
    if [[ $header =~ $etag_regex ]]; then
      etag=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    elif [[ -z $header ]]; then
      # End of headers
      break
    fi
  done
}

# Pass input first to parse_headers, then to jq
{
  parse_headers
  jq '._links.self'  # After parse_headers is done, only the JSON should remain
} < <(curl ...)
echo "ETag is $etag"
```

Example output

```
{
  "href": "https://ci.example.com/go/api/admin/pipelines/my_pipeline"
}
ETag is "e064ca0fe5d8a39602e19666454b8d77"
```

Comment: This prints what i wanted to the screen when the jq is updated. however where did the json colours come from? how does it print the json to screen? what in the world is happening?

Comment: If `jq` detects its output is a terminal device, it works as if the `-C` option is in effect, which means it will add escape sequences to its output for the terminal to interpret as color-changing instructions. If you don't want colored output, use the `-M` option to disable it (which is the default if you write the output to a file).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should store the response in a variable, and use it to access the `ETag:` header and the json.

Give a try to this:

```
response="$(curl -s 'https://ci.example.com/go/api/admin/pipelines/my_pipeline' \
-u 'username:password' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v6+json' \
-i)"
etag_header=$(printf '%s' "${response}" | sed -n '/^ETag.*/ { p }')
body_json="{${response#*{}"

# use etag_header
printf "%s\n" "${etag_header}"

# use body_json
printf "%s\n" "${body_json}" | jq
```

Output:

```
ETag: "e064ca0fe5d8a39602e19666454b8d77"
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://ci.example.com/go/api/admin/pipelines/my_pipeline"    
    }
  },
  "doc": {
    "href": "https://api.gocd.org/#pipeline-config"
  },
...
```